# Tokenizer only prints the first token

Tags: c, tokenize, c-strings

I am having trouble building a tokenizer. I am new to c++ and was wondering if anyone could help.

When I run the program, I enter the user input as "x = a + 1". When i do this, the only token output is the `x`. I want to display `"x\n = a\n +\n 1\n"`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

 char *text = (char*)malloc ( 40 *sizeof( char ));
 cout << "Enter the first arrangement of data." << endl;
 cin >> text;
 char *token = strtok(text, " ");
 while ( token )
 {
     if ( strlen(token) > 0 )
     {
        printf(" %s", token);
     }
     token = strtok(NULL, " ");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should  `#include <cstring>` to use `strtok()`.

Comment: Also, note that `sizeof(char)` is **always** 1.

Comment: i thought that (char*)malloc ( 40 *sizeof( char )) created a size of 40, would creating an array help fix it do you think?

Comment: It does, but multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is redundant, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the entire input.

Change

```
cin >> text;
```

to

```
cin.getline(text, 40);
```

Comment: I input "x = a + 1". if i alter my code so that text = " x = a + 1", the same problem persists.

Comment: That done it, i understand it better now i was only reading the first part of the input. Thanks

Comment: You now read the entire input line, instead of just the first letter. Your tokenizer loop is fine.